# Case sensitive order using Java Collator

Tags: java, string, sorting, localization, collation

I am trying to understand how case sensitive order should really work using [Java Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

In [this example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207) following strings are sorted in French locale using all strengths (I have added a few extra strings to the data set for illustrative purposes):

```
[Äbc, äbc, Àbc, àbc, Abc, abc, ABC] - Original Data
[Äbc, äbc, Àbc, àbc, Abc, abc, ABC] Primary
[Abc, abc, ABC, Àbc, àbc, Äbc, äbc] Secondary
[abc, Abc, ABC, àbc, Àbc, äbc, Äbc] Tertiary

Case kicks in only with Tertiary Collation Strength  : 
[CACHE, cache, Cache, da, DA, Da] - Original Data
[CACHE, cache, Cache, da, DA, Da] Primary
[CACHE, cache, Cache, da, DA, Da] Secondary
[cache, Cache, CACHE, da, Da, DA] Tertiary
```

But the result I was really expecting was this:

```
[abc, àbc, äbc, Abc, ABC, Àbc, Äbc] Tertiary
[cache, da, Cache, CACHE, Da, DA] Tertiary
```

In other words, I would like all lowercase go first (sorted alphabetically), followed by uppercase (or vice versa). Is this not a reasonable expectation?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. Would you like the Collator to behave differently by design or the result surprises you?

Comment: I would like to get different results, and was surprised to get whatever I got. So my question is - if this by design, and if yes - how to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: well String compareTo by default uses lexicographic ordering. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29 Do you want something different?

Comment: `compareTo` is not very useful as it does not order strings in localized contexts but by order defined in Unicode. I need to order text in arbitrary locales.

Comment: I would use Collator with the locale plus FULL_DECOMPOSITION if your locale includes really ä and umlaut stuff. unfortunately i cannot try it now but I think you will achieve your goal like this. I bookmark your question to make a more precise analysis.

Comment: How exactly decomposition is supposed to help? Decomposition is only relevant for special characters (umlauts, etc.) but with or without umlauts, sorting is not working as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37318/discussion-between-blackbird014-and-mindas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, the [android javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html) is somewhat more helpful than the oracle one - in particular:

> A tertiary difference is ignored when there is a primary or secondary difference anywhere in the strings.

Also worth noting: the order you get is what you would expect in French locale. According to the [wikipedia article on "ordre alphabétique"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classement_alphab%C3%A9tique#Lettres_accentu.C3.A9es):

> En première analyse, les caractères accentués, de même que les majuscules, ont le même rang alphabétique que le caractère fondamental.
>   Si plusieurs mots ont le même rang alphabétique, on tâche de les distinguer entre eux grâce aux majuscules et aux accents (pour le e, on a l'ordre e, é, è, ê, ë)

In English (my addition in italic):

> The first step consists in ranking letters, regardless of their accentuation or case (*i.e.: a,A,à rank the same*). If several words have the same rank following the first step, case and accentuation are taken into account.

In other words, `c` (small cap) and `D` (large cap) will always be sortable with a Primary strength and the Tertiary strength won't change that order.

So in your example, you will always have `cache` before `da`, regardless of case and accents. Case will only make a difference if the primary letter is the same (`c` (small) vs. `C` (large) for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't speak French and can't really comment if this requirement is strong and in what context does it appear, but in my native language there's no such requirement yet I get the same results as in French. My main point is that people are used to this kind of sort where uppercase letters come before lowercase ones, mainly because of [historical reasons](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). How does it work in other programming languages? Also it's quite odd internet is mysteriously silent on this subject.

Comment: @mindas: Collation is about human language order not about technical ASCII order. Using a collator is a conscious decision *against* lexicographical (ASCII or Unicode) ordering.

Comment: @mindas what I'm trying to say is (a) it was works as advertised and (b) it happens to be the correct alphabetical order (the order you'd find in a dictionary) in French.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code is working as intended. You can use custom collation rules to get the desired output.

[RuleBasedCollator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) is the only subclass of Collator in JDK. Your call to Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE) returns an instance of RuleBasedCollator

You could create your own instance using

```
RuleBasedCollator myCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(rules);
```

The format for rules is given in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: if you need to customize the rules of a locale, you can try using RuleBasedCollator:

```
    RuleBasedCollator collTemp = (RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);

    String usRules = collTemp.getRules();

    //Remove dashes rule from US locale (dashes come after letters)
    usRules = usRules.replace(",'-'", "");

    //Create a collator with customized rules    
    RuleBasedCollator coll = new RuleBasedCollator(usRules);

    //Sort the collection based on collator
    Collections.sort(lines, coll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not make assumptions about the resulting ordering of a locale-sensitive collator.

It’s not meant to reflect technical aspects like ASCII order but human language rules, e.g. as people would sort titles of books in a library or names in a phone book. You won’t find shelfs with uppercase books separated from shelfs with lowercase ones, usually.

To illustrate more surprising behavior, look at the following example:

```
String s1="IDONTCARE", s2="idontcare";
System.out.println("Comparing '"+s1+"' and '"+s2+"' locale sensitive");
Locale[] all={ Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("tr") };
for(Locale l:all)
{
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println(l);
  Collator c1=Collator.getInstance(l);
  c1.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
  System.out.println("primary:\t"+c1.compare(s1, s2));
  c1.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
  System.out.println("secondary:\t"+c1.compare(s1, s2));
  c1.setStrength(Collator.TERTIARY);
  System.out.println("tertiary:\t"+c1.compare(s1, s2));
  c1.setStrength(Collator.IDENTICAL);
  System.out.println("identical:\t"+c1.compare(s1, s2));
}
```

It will print:

```
Comparing 'IDONTCARE' and 'idontcare' locale sensitive

en
primary:    0
secondary:  0
tertiary:   1
identical:  1

tr
primary:    -1
secondary:  -1
tertiary:   -1
identical:  -1
```

As said, don’t expect to know the result and forget about the ASCII/Unicode lexicographic order with collators.